# What is an ideal way of debugging a segmentation fault in ROS?

Tags: ros, gdb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I generally use gdb to debug my run time errors in my C++ programs. But in ros as it spins n waits for the msgs in topics, the gdb doesn't really work well. So I want to know if there is another method to debug the ros codes when they run into segmentation faults.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29677/what-is-an-ideal-way-of-debugging-a-segmentation-fault-in-ros?/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can launch nodes directly in gdb, here is some more info:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For debugging ROS nodes I use the same way as for any other C++ program: gdb/ddd/kdbg.

The spinning shouldn't be a problem, just start of with the message handler in the backtrace. This is under the assumption that you want to debug your ROS code and not the ROS core functionality, which I would consider mostly bug-free.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on 2017-08-22**:
I am not very experienced with using gdb and ddd. How would I go about debugging nodes launched with roslaunch using ddd? Thanks!